# ReportViewer auto print results in stretched cells C# .NET Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, printing, rendering, reportviewer

Hopefully the title is self explanatory. I am auto-printing my reports using [this code](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/MSDNBlogsFS/prod.evol.blogs.msdn.com/CommunityServer.Components.PostAttachments/00/09/44/78/69/ReportPrintDocument.cs)

More here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brianhartman/2009/02/27/manually-printing-a-report/

I have made one change to the original code: m_pageSettings.Landscape = true;

I call the AutoPrint() method in my TestResults_Load after generating the report

```
private void AutoPrint()
{
    ReportPrintDocument autoprintme = new ReportPrintDocument(reportViewer1.LocalReport);
    autoprintme.Print();
}
```

Everything works fine except that the cells are stretched as shown in the picture and I can't fit everything on one page. If I print from the ReportViewer Preview dialog everything looks great.

I believe the problem is in PrintReportSample when it renders the pages, but I can't find any way of fixing it, and it doesn't seem like others are having the same issue.  There is a known issue with Server Reports but I believe it is unrelated.

I've lost at least half of my day trying to figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Top: auto print, Bottom: printed from preview dialog]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a couple of other autoprint classes that others had written with similar issues, but I found that if I rendered the page in portrait everything looked exactly as it would have had I printed it from the ReportViewer Preview.

As a workaround I removed some columns from my report and moved some information to the page header...it ended up looking really good.

I think I probably just don't understand what is happening in ReportPrintDocument.cs and it's not written for rendering landscape...but I have to say everything looks like it should work.